# Java class doesn't have to match package written in source file

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, package, filepath

in my project I wrote java class but by mistake put it into subfolder which is not same as mentioned package in source file. By chance I wrote this code not in some IDE therefore didn't noticed the mistake.
My build system is maven and surprisingly the class was compiled and put into correct subdirectory of generated class files without any error.
How can I configure maven compiler plugin or other maven plugin to recognize such mismatch when compile ?

Comment: Why not just use an IDE?

Comment: First Maven can't be configured this because this is done by the Java compiler...furthermore I strongly recommend to use an IDE...

Comment: @khmarbaise could you just recommend a bit less strongly because my monitor still shakes with fear after reading your recommendation and its uncomfortable to read the text ;-D

Comment: IDE also wouldn't help much, usually just a warning  at package definition line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how I can prevent such mismatch - it can be done by using CheckStyle PackageDeclaration module([javadoc](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/PackageDeclarationCheck.html))